# Page not Found 404 in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to route the following dropdown to a specific part of a controller, I keep getting Page not found when going to the link:http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignees/custom?datacenter=RDC03,

here's my route(s):

```
Route::resource('cards','CardController');
Route::resource('customers','CustomerController');
Route::resource('assignees','AssigneeController');
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('searchcard', 'AssigneeController@searchcard')->name('searchcard');
Route::get('returncard/{id}', 'AssigneeController@returncard')->name('returncard');
Route::get('custom', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('custom');
```

here is the view from index.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('custom') }}">
    <div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
        <label>Data Center:</label>
        <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
            <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
            <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
            <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
            <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function custom(Request $request)
{
    // You will have access to the datacenter using $request->datacenter
    $assignees = assignee::findorfail($request->datacenter)->paginate(10);

    return view('assignees.custom',compact('assignees'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

and here is the path to custom.blade.php:

```
resources/views/assignees/custom.blade.php
```

here is my current route:list:

```
 Domain | Method    | URI                       | Name              | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                         |                   | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                  |                   | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | assignees                 | assignees.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@index                          | web          |
|        | POST      | assignees                 | assignees.store   | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@store                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | assignees/create          | assignees.create  | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@create                         | web          |
|        | DELETE    | assignees/{assignee}      | assignees.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@destroy                        | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | assignees/{assignee}      | assignees.update  | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@update                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | assignees/{assignee}      | assignees.show    | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@show                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | assignees/{assignee}/edit | assignees.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@edit                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | autocomplete              | autocomplete      | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@autocomplete                   | web          |
|        | POST      | cards                     | cards.store       | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@store                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cards                     | cards.index       | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@index                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cards/create              | cards.create      | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@create                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cards/{card}              | cards.show        | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@show                               | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | cards/{card}              | cards.update      | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@update                             | web          |
|        | DELETE    | cards/{card}              | cards.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@destroy                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | cards/{card}/edit         | cards.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\CardController@edit                               | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | custom                    | assignee.custom   | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@custom                         | web          |
|        | POST      | customers                 | customers.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@store                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customers                 | customers.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customers/create          | customers.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@create                         | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | customers/{customer}      | customers.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@update                         | web          |
|        | DELETE    | customers/{customer}      | customers.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@destroy                        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customers/{customer}      | customers.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | customers/{customer}/edit | customers.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@edit                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                      | home              | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                     | login             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | login                     |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                    | logout            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email            | password.email    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset            | password.request  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset            | password.update   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}    | password.reset    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                  | register          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register                  |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | returncard/{id}           | returncard        | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@returncard                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | searchcard                | searchcard        | App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@searchcard                     | web
```

Comment: Have you got a `assignees/{id}` route ? because if this route is declared before this one, `custom` will be captured as an id so you have to add `with->('id', '\d+');` for the id route or declare this route before the second ;)

Comment: @JulienMetral I have included all the routes I have in my web.php,
there is route assignees/{assignee} before customs,

Comment: So i think you have to modify this route as well : `Route::get('assignees/custom', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('custom');` because your 404 is on this url : [http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignees/custom?datacenter=RDC03](http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignees/custom?datacenter=RDC03)

Comment: @JulienMetral, that url is being generated from the button click from the dropdown list.

Comment: you need just try custom.index, the best one can you php artisan route list and see your name of route

Comment: I have added the current routes into my question

Comment: `assignees/custom` is handled by `App\Http\Controllers\AssigneeController@show` currenty because it matches `GET|HEAD | assignees/{assignee}`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function custom(Request $request)
{
    // You will have access to the datacenter using $request->datacenter
    $assignees = assignee::findorfail($request->datacenter)->paginate(10);

    return view('assignees.custom',compact('assignees'));
}
```

Just remove `with()` and try

**Updated Answer**

```
<form action="{{ route('assignee.custom') }}">
    <div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
        <label>Data Center:</label>
        <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
            <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
            <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
            <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
            <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i am getting the same error, the error is relating to the routing and link which is being generated from the button.

Comment: @Abdul: Please display button which have link

Comment: you had 'assignee" and its  supposed to be "assignees", I fixed it.
here is the generated link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignees/custom?datacenter=RDC46

and I am getting page is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this :

```
Route::get('/custom', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('assignee.custom');
Route::resource('cards','CardController');
Route::resource('customers','CustomerController');
Route::resource('assignees','AssigneeController');
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('searchcard', 'AssigneeController@searchcard')->name('searchcard');
Route::get('returncard/{id}', 'AssigneeController@returncard')->name('returncard');
```

and

```
<form action="{{ route('assignee.custom') }}">
```

if this it's because of the `Route::resource('assignees','AssigneeController');` that generates a route `assignees/{assignee}` without any regular expression, so your assignees/custom route is catch with this route

Comment: I am getting another error which says  route is not defined."Route [assignees.custom] not defined. 
(View: /Users/Documents/Laravel/blog/resources/views/assignees/index.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Route [assignees.custom] not defined. (0)"

Comment: Sorry it's `assignee.custom`

Comment: the button is generating the following url"
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom?datacenter=RDC46" so i am getting a page not found error.

Comment: I think now it's the good route but it's your `findorfail` that fails and gives you a 404, findOrFail finding the first record that have as id `RDC03` in your case.
Can you try : `dd(assignee::find($request->datacenter))` in your controller ?
If it doesn't find anything it's because you don't have record with ` RDC03`in our database